# 404 on rails js call, possibly incorrect route definition

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm getting the following javascript error when clicking a link meant to load some data in to a partial:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/activate_foo_path 404 (Not Found)
```

I have the following link:

```
<%=link_to foo.name, "activate_#{foo.name.gsub(' ', '_').downcase}_path", :remote => true %>
```

Here is my route entry:

```
get "activate_foo" => 'bar#activate_foo', :as => :activate_foo
```

The controller method:

```
 def activate_foo
    @bars = Bar.includes(:fobs).where(:fobs => {:id => 1})
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

I have a file views/bars/activate_foo.js with the contents:

```
$("#bar-listings").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'foo', locals: { bars: @bars } ) %>");
```

Here is the div that should be replaced:

```
<div id="data-service-listings">
    <p>Whatever</p>
</div>
```

Then I have _foo.html.erb:

```
<% @bars.each do |bar| %>
   Do stuff with <%= bar %>
<% end %>
```

I have a feeling that my route is written wrong.  I've tried messing around with it and moving files around.

Also, feel free to offer overall suggestions on the strategy I'm using.

Thanks.

Edit: updated the link definition.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you need to include the model instance in the call to `foo_path` if you want to link to a specific resource. The code below is the more Railsy way of going about this:

**routes.rb**

```
resource :businesses

get 'activate_billing/:id' => 'billing#activate', :as => :activate_billing
```

I'm a little rusty on my Rails routes, so the route for `activate_billing` might be incorrect.

**businesses_controller.rb**

```
class BusinessesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @businesses = Business.all
    end
end
```

**app/views/businesses/index.html.erb**

```
<% @businesses.each |business| do
    <%= link_to business.name, activate_billing_path(business), :remote => true %><br>
<% end %>
```

The call to `activate_billing_path` gets passed the `business` object, which should set the Id `param` in the controller, and generate a URL like: `/activate_billing/123` where `123` is `business.id`.

**billing_controller.rb**

```
class BillingController < ApplicationController
    def activate
        business = Business.find(params[:id])
        business.billing.activate
        render :success
    end
end
```

The controller just sends back a 200 OK response, unless you need to render something specific. It's hard to tell with the code you've included in your question.

Comment: I made the mistake of putting the html output of the link in my question.  Please see the update.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling link_to with a two strings as parameters:

```
<%=link_to foo.name, "activate_#{foo.name.gsub(' ', '_').downcase}_path", :remote => true %>
```

In this, the first argument is: foo.name, which is fine.

The second argument is "activate_#{foo.name.gsub(' ', '_').downcase}_path" which will just be a string in the same way as "http://www.google.com" is a string.

What you want is the result of "activate_#{foo.name.gsub(' ', '_').downcase}_path" so an ugly way to make this happen would be to eval it:

```
<%=link_to foo.name, eval("activate_#{foo.name.gsub(' ', '_').downcase}_path"), :remote => true %>
```

But this allows all sorts of XSS and dangers so I suggest you consider re-thinking this functionality.

Comment: I have actaully changed the link to: `<%= link_to business_domain.name, activate_billing_path(:business_domain_id => business_domain.id), :remote => true %>`.  I am still getting similar errors.  I have updated the path in routes.rb to `get "activate_billing" => 'data_services#activate_billing', :as => :activate_billing`.